# How to map array and keep certain properties of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am looking to map through and array and return an array that has only certain properties of the original object. For example from here:

```
[
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
   },
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"},
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"}
   ]
```

produce this:

```
[
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679
   },
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679
    },
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679
   }
   ]
```

Not sure if mapping over is the right way to think about this?

Comment: yup.. use map, ex: let newArr = originalArr.map(a => ({ lat: a.lat, lon: a.lon }));

Answer (score 3):

```js
const list = [
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
   },
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"},
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"}
   ];
   
const result = list.map( o => { return { lat: o.lat, lon: o.lon} });
// or
const result1 = list.map(({lat, lon}) => ({lat, lon}));

console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
```

You can use `map` method

Answer (score 0):

Mapping will work.

```js
const array = [{
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
  },
  {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
  },
  {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
  }
]

const mappedArray = array.map(item => ({
  lat: item.lat,
  lon: item.lon
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes need

```js
let arr=[
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
   },
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"},
   {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"}
   ];
   
   console.log(arr.map(({ lat, lon }) => ({lat, lon})));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
  },
  {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
  },
  {
    lat: 40.621996,
    lon: -74.028679,
    places: 1,
    time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
  }
];

const res = data.map(({lat, lon}) => ({lat, lon}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with map

```
var data = [
            {
              lat: 40.621996,
              lon: -74.028679,
              places: 1,
              time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"
            },
            {
             lat: 40.621996,
             lon: -74.028679,
             places: 1,
             time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"},
            {
             lat: 40.621996,
             lon: -74.028679,
             places: 1,
             time: "2019/11/20 22:26:00"}
             ];

var newData = data.map((d)=>{
 ['places', 'time'].forEach(e => delete d[e]);
 return d;
});
```